# Dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is--

If $W_1=\{(0,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5):x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \in \mathbb R\}$ and $W_2=\{(x_1,0,x_3,x_4,x_5): x_1,x_3,x_4,x_5\in \mathbb R\}$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^5$ then what is the dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2$?

answer key says the answer is 2.

$W_1 \cap W_2$  is of type $\{(0,0,x_3,x_4,x_5)\}$. so this must be of dimension 3. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I believe your reasoning is correct. Perhaps the answer key is wrong.

Comment: As you have written the question, the correct answer is 3. Double-check the problem statement and the solution.

Comment: Statement of the question is right. I was not confident about the answer. So I guess there is some mistake in the answer key.